# Why does placing text directly in a <div class"col"> break the bootstrap column system

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This may be a foolish question, but why does this jsbin link:

https://jsbin.com/gukidacero/edit?html,output

Handle the bootstrap column system incorrectly by stacking "col stack vertically" vertically when there is text directly in the div class "col".  What am I doing wrong?  I have seen examples like this on bootstrap's page.

For me in jsbin the output looks like:

col stack horizontally col stack horizontally

col stack vertically

col stack vertically

col stack vertically

col stack vertically

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col navbar-text">col stack horizontally</div>
      <div class="col navbar-text">col stack horizontally</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">col stack vertically</div>
      <div class="col">col stack vertically</div>
      <div class="col">col stack vertically</div>
      <div class="col">col stack vertically</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean break?

Comment: There is no `col` class in Bootstrap 3. It's new to Bootstrap 4: http://www.codeply.com/go/tzYgcCJ5Jh Which version do you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `.col` class in [bootstrap v3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) - you're using it wrong:

> Grid columns are created by specifying the number of twelve available columns you wish to span. For example, three equal columns would use three `.col-xs-4`.

However, in  [bootstrap v4 there is a `.col` class](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#auto-layout-column).

Note: those styles come from `.navbar-text` class - if you inspect the elements you'll see the applied styles:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)       
    .navbar-text {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 15px;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
}

.navbar-text {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```